# Can anyone explain how multiple input works in this python 3 program(like d and d[0],d[1])?

Tags: python-3.x

Why we have to take d[0] and d[1] instead of another input() command separately?

```
n = int(input())
s = set(map(int, input().split())) 
N = int(input())
for i in range(N):
    d = input().split()
    if d[0] =="pop":
        s.pop()
    elif d[0] == "remove":
         s.remove(int(d[1]))
    elif d[0] == "discard":
         s.discard(int(d[1]))
 print(sum(s))
```

Comment: You could do it that way too.  This lets you have the command (`pop`, `remove`, `discard`) and the value on the same line.  `discard 1` `pop 3` etc.